# Convert React/javascript string array of objects to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, string

This seems like a trivial issues but I can't get it working properly. I'm fairly new to JS/React so that is working against me also.

This is the response I get back (it's a TS object type but is actually a plain string so I can't iterate it and it just isn't useful):

```
[{"answer": "Within 2 weeks", "question": "Moving/Purchase date"}, {"answer": "2 bedrooms", "question": "Bedrooms (minimum) ?"}]
```

How can I convert that into an array of objects so I can iterate through them? Like so;

```
[
    0: { "answer": "Yes", "question": "Are you sure?" },
    1: { "answer": "False", "question": "Do you hold a valid passport?" }
]
```

I've tried doing JSON.parse and creating a Map but it doesn't provide the expected output. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks all! :)

Comment: It already is an array... If you mean that it's a JSON string then just `JSON.parse` it, but from the typings it seems like it's already an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort it using the following:

```
const arrayObj = JSON.parse(results as unknown as string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)?

Of course it's risky to use if your system allows arbitrary Javascript code to be executed, but if you're sure running code from a string, here converting the code (the array inside it if it were to be a line of code) in the string to an array object isn't harmful in your environment, use it.

```js
let str = '[{"answer": "Within 2 weeks", "question": "Moving/Purchase date"}, {"answer": "2 bedrooms", "question": "Bedrooms (minimum) ?"}]';

let obj = eval(str);
console.log(obj, typeof(obj));

for (const element of obj){
    console.log(element);
} ;
```

I've used [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and it seems to be working too (recommended option):

```js
let str = '[{"answer": "Within 2 weeks", "question": "Moving/Purchase date"}, {"answer": "2 bedrooms", "question": "Bedrooms (minimum) ?"}]';

let obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj, typeof(obj));

for (const element of obj){
    console.log(element);
} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

pass your array str in this line you get your output in obj. like this
const obj = Object.assign({}, str);

Comment: This is a low quality answer, take the effort to make a runnable snippet and give more explanation

Answer (score -1):

If you want to wrap it inside another object with indices being the keys then you can use reduce.

```js
const list = [{
  "answer": "Within 2 weeks",
  "question": "Moving/Purchase date"
}, {
  "answer": "2 bedrooms",
  "question": "Bedrooms (minimum) ?"
}]

const newList = list.reduce((acc, x, i) => [...acc, {
  [i]: x
}], []);

console.log(newList)
```

Comment: I highly doubt that this is what the question is asking for.